# How do I get the gradle eclipse plugin to build a classpath including my additional java test task dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, visual-studio-code, gradle-plugin

I started with a brand new java-library project generated by the `gradle init` task. Then I added an integrationTest task by following the steps given from the gradle java plugin user guide: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests. But now the gradle eclipse plugin does not include the intTestImplementation dependencies in the .classpath file. Everything compiles, tests, and runs fine using `gradle build test` tasks, but because .classpath is missing the intTestImplementation dependencies VSCode is saying that my integration test classes are using undefined types.

I tried tweaking configs shown in this doc about the gradle eclipse plugin but nothing I've tried there has helped. https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.html

Here is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'eclipse'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

sourceSets {
    intTest {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    }
}

configurations {
    intTestImplementation.extendsFrom implementation
    intTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
}

dependencies {
    intTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = 'Runs integration tests.'
    group = 'verification'

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.intTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.intTest.runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter test
}
```

and running `gradlew eclipse` generates a classpath like this missing the junit dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/default"/>
    <classpathentry output="bin/main" kind="src" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="main"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test,intTest"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry output="bin/main" kind="src" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="main"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test,intTest"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry output="bin/test" kind="src" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry output="bin/test" kind="src" path="src/test/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry output="bin/intTest" kind="src" path="src/intTest/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="intTest"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="intTest"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-10/"/>
</classpath>
```

I would expect that `gradle eclipse` task would generate the .classpath file with the junit dependency, but it's missing.

Comment: Tried this in intelliJ and it has no problems. but of course it's not using the gradle eclipse plugin.

Comment: Did you try the eclipse configuration mentioned here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38207361/5065946

Answer (score 0):

I have also struggled with integration tests. This is my solution which work for me.

Change the sourceSet :

```
sourceSets{
    intTest {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        java.srcDirs=files('src/intTest/java')
        resources.srcDirs=files('src/intTest/resources')
    }

}
```

That should fix the classpath

Also I faced another issue : my integration test ran with .gradlew integration, but in VS Code, I get one compilation error, a library was not found despite the dependency (only set for the integration test task) was well added with

```
intTestImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner'
```

and when I clicked on "Run test" in VScode I get a compilation exception. It might be a bug in VSCode because I also try in intelliJ same code no error, integration tests ran well in intellij ui.

To remove the error I've added also the dependency for test with :

```
testImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner'
```